# Add class to multiple elements with multiple data attributes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, attributes

**What I need:**
I have a large data set that have multiple attributes on them. I need to search through the data set and apply a css class if they contain a certain attribute -- such as country. In the example below, I want to be able to click a button and change every element that has the data attribute 'usa' to a new class, blue.

**What I have:**
I have applied multiple data attributes to each element. While I know this isn't directly supported, I am using javascript to split them into an array. Then, I'm trying to target all arrays on the page and add a class to them if they contain a value (such as country name). What I can't figure out is how to target ALL arrays on the page and then if I do, how to apply classes directly to the ones that contain the particular attribute.

Here is a simplified mockup:

```
<div id="collection">
<div class="countries" data-place="usa;canada;mexico"></div>
<div class="countries" data-place="usa;ireland;france"></div>
<div class="countries" data-place="spain;canada;mexico"></div>
<div class="countries" data-place="usa;spain;france"></div>
<div class="countries" data-place="portugal;canada;ireland"></div>
</div>

<button class="unitedstates">Change USA to Blue</button>

<script>

var data = document.getElementById('collection').getAttribute('data-country');
var arr = data.split(';');

$(".unitestates").click(function () {
console.log(arr);
    if (jQuery.inArray('usa', arr) > -1) {
        $("#countries").addClass('blue')
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you add the collection to snippet so arr is not null

Comment: The div element doesn't have the attribute `data-country`

Comment: The class `unitedstates` wasn't spelt correctly here though `$(".unitestates").click(function (){...`

Comment: I'd advise against using `blue` as a class name. Use something like `highlight`. I once had to refactor HTML/CSS that had the following: `.red { color: black; font-weight: bold; }`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [Attribute Contains Selector [name*=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) to select all elements that has *usa* in the *data-place* attribute:

```js
$(".unitedstates").click(function() {  
  $('[data-place*="usa"]').addClass('mark');
});
```

```css
.mark {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collection">
  <div class="countries" data-place="usa;canada;mexico">1</div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="usa;ireland;france">2</div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="spain;canada;mexico">3</div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="usa;spain;france">4</div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="portugal;canada;ireland">5</div>
</div>

<button class="unitedstates">Change USA to Blue</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can re-format your code as follow:**

- Use the jQuery built-in function `data` to get attributes `data-*`.
- Use the `some`function to check if an array meets a specific condition.  In your case this condition: `c === country`.

**Look at this snippet code:**

```js
$(".unitestates").click(function() {
  var country = $('#collection').data('country');

  $('.countries').each(function() {
    var countries = $(this).data('place').split(';');
    if (countries.some( (c) => c === country ) ) {
      $(this).addClass('blue');
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.blue {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100px;
  height: 10px;
  margin-top: 5px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="collection" data-country='usa'>
  <div class="countries" data-place="usa;canada;mexico"></div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="usa;ireland;france"></div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="spain;canada;mexico"></div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="usa;spain;france"></div>
  <div class="countries" data-place="portugal;canada;ireland"></div>
</div>

<button class="unitestates">Change USA to Blue</button>
```

## Resources

- [`.data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/)
- [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)